# populate custom List View from editText

Tags: android, android-listview

I'd like to populate the custom List View with data from EditText in run time. How could I achive it? .....................................................................................................................................................................
My code so far:

```
package com.example.additemlistrun;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.ListActivity;

public class MainListActivity extends ListActivity {
    public ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    static String[] mTilte;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_list);

        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override``
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                String gettingdata = et.getText().toString();

                              // Unable to pass data from editext to MyAdapter class

                mTilte[0] = gettingdata;
            MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(MainListActivity.this, mTilte);
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
    }
}
class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    Context context;
    String[] ArrayTitle;

    MyAdapter(Context c, String[] title) {
        super(c, R.layout.single_row, title);
        this.context = c;
        this.ArrayTitle = title;    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, parent, false);

        TextView titles = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        titles.setText(ArrayTitle[position]);

        return row;
    }
}
```

Logcat error ::

[image]

Comment: what error are you getting? post logcat, your activity XML and describe error please

Comment: Error Logcat has been add. it have null pointer Exception .

Comment: @user3741815 what code is in line 38??

Comment: i'm assign value to String title[]. the value getting from editText is converting in String and assigning it to String[] gettingdata and in next line i'm assigning Tilte[0] = gettingdata

Comment: Just a reminder that if any of the answers helped you, you should accent the one that helped as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You null pointer might be happening here:

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

The view is not found - you need to declare that EditText (and ListView) as an Activity variables and assign them before you assign the onClickListener. Try this:

```
public class MainListActivity extends ListActivity {
    public ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    static String[] mTilte;
    EditText et;
    ListView list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_list);

        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        mTilte = new String[]{};
        list = getListView();

        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                String gettingdata = et.getText().toString();
                mTilte[0] = gettingdata;
            MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(MainListActivity.this, mTilte);
                list.setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
    }
}
```